# Accessing Lucene.net in SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, lucene.net, lucene

I am using lucene.net index for fast retrieval. Now I am accessing the lucene.net indexed file by c# code. Is there any option to access the lucene.net data directly from SQL Server?

Comment: You can use CLR within sql, but there are two problems, lucence needs its indices files, and this needs higher security permissions, and it has low performance because of sql to clr pipeline. I don't know another option.

Comment: @ Yasser Moradi Thanks for your comment. Performance may be an issue for this.

Comment: Why are you involving SQL?  If it's because you require data from it.  Then probably you should be storing that in lucene in the first place.  Maybe describe your scenario a bit more.